# $\beta$-mixing in Asmptotically Stochasitic (Random) Process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, stationary-processes

This issue involves a very important concept, which is the **$\beta$-mixing** nature of **stochastic processes**. All the stochastic processes we discuss are time-positive and discrete. To strictly adhere to this concept, we first introduce it:

---

- **($\beta$-mixing)** Firstly, this concept is limited to **markov process** $\left\{ Z_t \right\} _{t\geqslant 1}$. We assume that **markov processes have a unique stationary distribution $\nu$**. When $\left\{ Z_t \right\} _{t\geqslant 1}$ has **exponential ergodicity**, there exists $\beta$-mixing coefficients $\beta(t)$, i.e.
  $$
  \beta \left( t \right) =\mathop {\mathrm{sup}} \limits_{k\geqslant 1}\mathbb{E} \left[ \mathop {\mathrm{sup}} \limits_{\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{F} _{k+t:\infty}}\left| \mathbb{P} \left( \mathcal{B} |\mathcal{F} _{1:k} \right) -\mathbb{P} \left( \mathcal{B} \right) \right| \right] ,
  $$
  where $\mathcal{F} _{n:m}=\sigma \left( \left\{ Z_n,\cdots ,Z_m \right\} \right) $, and $\beta \left( t \right) \leqslant C\exp \left( -bt \right) $ w.r.t. constants $C$ and $b$.
  See the following reference for more detail:

> Meitz, Mika, and Pentti Saikkonen. "Subgeometric ergodicity and β-mixing." Journal of Applied Probability 58.3 (2021): 594-608, Page 594.

We usually call this markov process is $\beta$-mixing.

---

Now we will divide the problem into two levels:

(**Q1**, Simple Baseline) Suppose there exists a **general process** $\left\{ X_t \right\} _{t\geqslant 1}$ with $\left| X_t \right|<\infty $ and $\mathbb{E} \left| X_t \right|<\infty $, $\mathbb{E} \left| X_t \right|^2<\infty $. Now truncate the process with **constant** time $N<\infty$. Construct a new process $\left\{ Z_t \right\} _{t\geqslant 1}$ where $Z_t=X_t$ a.s. when $t\leqslant N$, and $\left\{ Z_{N+t} \right\} _{t\geqslant 1}$ is a **$\beta$-mixing markov process**. Denote $\mathcal{F} _{n:m}=\sigma \left( \left\{ Z_n,\cdots ,Z_m \right\} \right) $.

**Question: Suppose $\mathcal{F} _{N+1:\infty}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F} _{1:N}$, can we also claim that $\left\{ Z_t \right\} _{t\geqslant 1}$ (note **it is not markovian**) is $\beta$-mixing?**

---

(**Corollary of Q1**) Suppose exists non-trivial constant $T\leqslant N<\infty $ satisfying $\frac{N}{T}=k\in \mathbb{N} _+$. We can "cut" $\left\{ Z_t \right\} _{t\geqslant 1}$ into
$$
\underbrace{Z_1,\cdots ,Z_T}_{H_1}, \underbrace{Z_{T+1},\cdots ,Z_{2T}}_{H_2}, \cdots , \underbrace{Z_{\left( k-1 \right) T+1},\cdots ,Z_{kT}}_{H_k}, \cdots  
$$
So $H_1$ means the $i$-th block in $\left\{ Z_t \right\} _{t\geqslant 1}$. We only sliced the process in Q1, so the conclusion of Q1 remains unchanged.

---

(**Q2**, Infinite Case) Now let $N = \infty$ and $T < \infty$. According to "cut" method above, suppose $H_i$ satisfies the following properties:

1. The initial state of $H_i$ is $Z_{\left( i-1 \right) T+1}$. **It is i.i.d. with $Z_{\left( i-1 \right) T}$**, the ternimal state of $H_{i-1}$. Denote $Z_{\left( i-1 \right) T+1}, Z_{\left( i-1 \right) T}\sim \mu _i$.
2. Moreover, **$\mathcal{F} _{\left( i-1 \right) T+1: iT}=\sigma \left(  H_i \right) $ is independent of $\mathcal{F} _{1:\left( i-1 \right) T}=\sigma \left( \left\{ H_1,\cdots ,H_{i-1} \right\} \right) $.**
3. Process in $H_i$ must be a truncation of a $\beta$-mixing markov process, i.e. $\left\{ Z_{\left( i-1 \right) T+t} \right\} _{t\geqslant 1}$ is a **$\beta$-mixing markov process** with stationary distribution $\nu _i$.

*Hint: So you cannot use any general Asymptotic Properties directly for markov process.*

4. There **exists limit distribution $\nu $ s.t. $D_{\mathrm{TV}}\left( \nu _i, \nu \right) \rightarrow 0$, and $D_{\mathrm{TV}}\left( \nu _{i-1}, \nu _i \right) \rightarrow 0$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$**. Also, suppose **$D_{\mathrm{TV}}\left( \mu _i, \nu _{i-1} \right) \rightarrow 0$**. The divergence $D_{\mathrm{TV}}$ means total variation distance.

*Hint: This condition is almost the most important, as it implies the relationship between random processes under different blocks. Although the partitioning of each process is independent, we suggest that over time, $H_i$ progresses towards a **strictly stationary process**, and the initial distribution of the next block is very close to the stationary distribution of the previous block.*

**Question: Can we claim that $\left\{ Z_t \right\} _{t\geqslant 1}$ (note it is not markovian) is $\beta$-mixing? Why?**

**Additional Question: If the answer is not, Can we achieve our final goal by fixing the proposition 4 above? I.e. convergence in probability or a.s. or ...**

Comment: Independence between $(X_1, ..., X_N)$ and $Z_{N+1}$ does not mean there is independence between $(X_1, ..., X_N)$ and $Z_{N+2}$ (just take the case $Z_{N+1}=0$ surely). Also, suppose $X_1$ is a random real number with digits in its base 10-expansion that completely specify the sample path of $\{Z_{N+2}, Z_{N+3}, ...\}$.

Comment: @Michael I think in Q1, the independence between $\mathcal{F}_{1:N}$ and $Z_{N+1}$ can prevent this from happening. In Q3, for each upcoming markov process, I assume that its initial state is independent of the previous process. Do you think this is not sufficient? Addendum (lastest): I may believe that the next state of a Markov process is completely determined by the previous state, so the previous state will not have an impact.

Comment: In particular, assume $N\geq 2$. Let $\{Z_{N+1}, Z_{N+2}, Z_{N+3}, ...\}$ be a 3-state DTMC with states $\{0,1,2\}$ and initial condition $Z_{N+1}=0$ surely (so $Z_{N+1}$ is independent of everything). Let  $X_1=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}Z_{N+i}10^{-i}$.

Comment: @Michael Sincerely thank you, I completely understand! What measures do you suggest I take to ensure that the proposition is meaningful?

Comment: If you have two independent random processes $(X_1, ..., X_N)$ and $(Z_{N+1}, Z_{N+2}, ...)$ you can always append them: $$\{X_1, X_2, ..., X_N, Z_{N+1}, Z_{N+2}, ...\}$$ and then the asymptotic properties depend only on the properties of $\{Z_{N+i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, indeed if the mixing property holds for that, then it will hold for the appended process.

Comment: @Michael Your timely reply makes me warm. However, my biggest concern is Q2. In fact, this is equivalent to performing an infinite (but countable) number of operations as you said. This makes me very worried about whether there may be a situation of taking things for granted.

Comment: Your Q2 assumes $N=\infty$, but it does not make sense to me to append a process at an infinite index. Your detailed description of Q2 has some other points, perhaps there are some more deatiled assumptions, but that seems too complicated for me to think about now. You may want to make that another question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the counter-example from my comments (simplified to take $N=1$):

Fix $N=1$.

- Define $\{Z_2, Z_3, Z_4, ...\}$ as a 3-state ergodic DTMC with state space $\{0,1,2\}$ and steady state distribution that is equally likely over all three states.
- Assume $Z_2=0$ surely (so $Z_2$ is independent of everything).
- Define $X_1=\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} Z_i10^{-i}$.

Then $X_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent but the process $(X_1, Z_2,Z_3, ...)$ does not have the conditional mixing property because knowing $X_1$ also gives you the full future $Z_i$ values.

---

You can get the mixing you want if you just concatenate two **independent** processes $(X_1, ..., X_N)$ and $(Z_{N+1}, Z_{N+2}, ...)$ to create $(X_1, ..., X_N, Z_{N+1}, Z_{N+2}, ...)$. The reason the above counter-example works is that, just because $(X_1, ..., X_N)$ is independent of $Z_{N+1}$ does not mean $(X_1, ..., X_N)$ is independent of $Z_{N+2}$.